# Playing online in another country?

Tags: ps4

Can you play online with a PS4 if it was purchased in another country?  I am buying it it Japan, and I live in Malaysia.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can purchase the Ps4 and use it anywhere.

"In general, neither digital nor disc-based games will be region locked, but PlayStation recommends that all users purchase games at the region of their residence to guarantee the best overall experience and customer service. In certain instances, a software publisher may choose to region lock a game title for specific reasons, but Sony Computer Entertainment expects these instances to be uncommon.
Read more at http://www.siliconera.com/2013/10/30/massive-playstation-4-faq-answers-questions/#i4eC4eCJW4cCrfXV.99"

Comment: thx !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Does Sony have regional stores?  If so, is it by continent or by country?

Comment: I'm not 100% on this one(As I don't own a PS4), but if its like XB1 in any way(which is also not region locked) you just set your region in the system settings and it does the translations/listings accordingly.